# Chess kings number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How to find  $2500$ chess kings number of arrangements on board $100\times100$? Is it possible to do that with just combinatorics? Will it be less then $(51^{50}\times2^{2500})$ and $(51^{100})$

Comment: Pretty safe to say it will be a _lot_ less than those numbers, assuming that the kings follow the rules of chess and can't be on squares next to or diagonal from one another.

Comment: ${10000\choose 2500}$ which is about $1.4\times 10^{2440}$, substantially larger than either of the numbers you mention.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614067/kings-on-a-chessboard . It may be a while before we get the answer for the $100 \times 100$ board.

Comment: @DougChatham: this question is different, we do not want to place $2n$ kings on a $2n\times 2n$ chessboard or something like that, but $n^2$ kings on a $2n\times 2n$ chessboard. There are very few ways to do that.

Comment: Oops!  Yeah, I misread the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you prove that there is exactly one king in every $2\times 2$ square giving a tiling of the original board (by the Dirichlet box principle, if there is an empty $2\times 2$ square, two kings lie in the same square, that gives a contradiction), you may label each $2\times 2$ square according to the position of the king in such a square, with a label from $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$. For instance, if a king is in the leftmost part of a square, it cannot be in the rightmost part of the square on the left and so on.

So the number of chess kings arrangements is given by the colourings of a $50\times 50$ chessboard, with colours from $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$, that fulfill a given set of constraints. However, they are very strict: assume that a king is in the leftmost part of a $2\times 2$ square that lies in the rightmost part of the original chessboard: any king in a square on the left of the previous $2\times 2$ square has to lie in the leftmost part, so the first component (left-right) of the labels is almost uniform along the lines of the $50\times 50$ chessboard ($LLL\ldots LR\ldots RRR$) and the second component (top-bottom) is almost uniform along the columns of the $50\times 50$ chessboard ($TTT\ldots TB\ldots BBB$). That gives the bound $51^{100}$, but we still have not accounted for diagonal adiacencies.

There are $2\cdot 49^2$ couples of diagonally adjacent squares in the $50\times 50$ chessboard. Assuming uniformity and independence, if we take a random colouring from the previous ones we may expect that a fixed couple of diagonal adjacent squares gives a colour conflict with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. But a colour conflict may happen only on the region that separates $L$ from $R$ or $T$ from $B$, and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ for a fixed couple of diagonally adjacent squares belonging to that region, so I am expecting that the total number of chess kings arrangements is given by something close to:
$$ 51^{100}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}\approx \color{red}{2^{467}}.$$

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your argument. More precisely, why can diagonal conflict happen "only on the region that separates $L$ from $R$ or $T$ from $B$"?

In a 4x4 grid (subdivided in 4 2x2 grids), a diagonal problem (not accounted for by the first argument) can only occur in two dual ways, one of which is given by the labelling


\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
BR & TR  \\
\hline
BL & TL\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: The first line is in the "region" RR, while the second is in the region LL. Similarly, the first column is in the region BB, while the second is in the region TT. 

Could you explain a bit more how you got your corrective factor of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$?