# General Solution to Kings on Chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, chessboard

This question was inspired by the numerous other king on chessboard questions asked on this site.
Specifically this one:

[Kings on a chessboard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614067/kings-on-a-chessboard?rq=1)

My question is "just more general: "What is the number of ways to place $k$ nonattacking kings of a $p \times q$  chessboard?"

I know that the solution incorporates generating function but I am unsure how to  use them.

Please help.

Comment: There are $\binom{pq}k$ ways to place $k$ kings on a $p\times q$ chessboard. (Assuming each king must be placed on a square of the chessboard, and no more than one king to a square.)

Comment: @bof There is an additional restriction mentioned in the linked question but not in this question: No two kings can attack each other.

Comment: Although the question you cite is less general than yours, [Einar Rødland's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614067/kings-on-a-chessboard/614099#614099) to that question nevertheless also seems to me to be an answer yours.